# Postgres SQL VSC Autocomplete

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Is there a way of hiding the useless autocomeplte from my sql code?
[image: I would like to get rude of useless complitions]

i would like the auto complete to show only sql related things and not spam alot of unknown and useless stuff, is there a way of doing it?

Comment: What plugin is doing the auto complete?

Comment: I dont know, is there a way of figuring it out?

Comment: OK, so down in the bottom-right of the window it will say what file-type it thinks you are editing. If you google "vscode file association" you will see how to change that. Different plugins offer different syntax highlighting/autocomplete options. Some will even query a database to get a list of tables and columns for autocomplete.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! its really informative :D
Is there another plugins to postgres sql?
i have only one